# Кодировка заголовка From

Tags: email, php, кодировка

Проблема в том, что русские буквы в заголовке `From` приходят на яндекс-почту в виде кракозябр. На другие почтовые сервисы все приходит корректно. Где, при отправке письма, можно задать кодировку конкретно этому заголовку?
Или, может быть, нужно поставить другую кодировку всему письму? Отправляю стандартный заголовок:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n
```

Comment: Если строго слеловать RFC, то 8-ми битные символы в любом заголовке письма **не допускаются**.

Их надо кодировать и для каждого такого поля писать в какой кодировке данное *поле заголовка*.

Comment: А можно немного поподробней, как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте начать с [этого](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2231).

А лучше посылайте всех с русскими буковками в заголовках e-mail ...

Comment: Слишком сложно :(. Мне нужно-то закодировать всего 1 слово и оно должно быть на русском.

Comment: В комментарий не влезло. Привел пример в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@andreyqin, как раз для "одного слова" пример из RFC, читать которое я Вам предложил

```
From: =?US-ASCII*EN?Q?Keith_Moore?= <moore@cs.utk.edu>
```

А также идете оттуда в [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047)

и читаете

```
2. Syntax of encoded-words
4. Encodings
```

Вот, например для

```
this is some text
```

получаем

```
=?iso-8859-1?q?this=20is=20some=20text?=
```

Т.е. делаете

```
=?кодировка?q?q-кодированный-текст?=
```

Идея **`Q`** кодировки проста, все кроме латинских букв и цифр заменяете на =XX (XX - 16-ричнеый код байта). Вместо iso-8859-1 напишите свою кодировку (например UTF-8).

Comment: @avp, каюсь, но с английским я не очень дружу. А проблему решил, вот код:
$headers .= "From: =?CP1251?B?" . base64_encode(iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251', 'Слово на русском')) . "?= \r\n";

Comment: Ну, я не пишу на ПХП, но если Вам так проще, то да, вместо Q- B-кодировка.

А зачем перекодировать UTF в CP1251? Лишняя работа. 

Также учтите, что в cp1251 Вы можете кодировать только русские символы (+ еще немного знаков), а в UTF любые. 

Кроме того, если в исходном тексте в utf будут символы, не представимые в cp1251, то iconv скорее всего вместо текста вернет ошибку. Но, как это реально в ПХП - надо проверять.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите что-то типа этого http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php#111124
Меня спасал в похожей ситуации base64

Comment: Пробовал base64 - все письмо становится кракозябрами. Пошел в лоб и сделал $from = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1251", "Строка");

  $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

  $headers .= "From: $from \r\n";
Но в таком случае на mail.ru не приходит вообще никакой заголовок.

Comment: кодируйте base64 как описано в rfc,